# How can I use an extension method without importing the whole namespace?

Tags: c#, datetime, static, namespaces, extension-methods

I am using the `Google.Api.CommonProtos` NuGet package with my C# service, and want to use the `Google.Type.Date` type alongside the `System.DateTime` type.  I also want to use the included extension methods to convert back and forth between `System.DateTime` and `Google.Type.Date`.

The problem is that when I import the extension method `.ToDate()`, it brings in the entire `Google.Type` namespace which causes `DateTime` to be ambiguous between `System.DateTime` and `Google.Type.DateTime`.  This code does not build:

```cs
using System;
using Google.Type;

namespace Example
{
    public class ExampleClass
    {
        public Google.Type.Date TomorrowDate(DateTime date) => date.AddDays(1).ToDate();
    }
}
// Error    CS0104  'DateTime' is an ambiguous reference between 'Google.Type.DateTime' and 'System.DateTime'
```

I am fine with being verbose when referencing a `Google.Type.DateTime`, but I don't want to start rewriting all uses of `DateTime` in our app to say `System.DateTime`.  How can I achieve this?  Effectively, how can I use extension methods defined in a specific class without importing (`using` in C#) the entire namespace where the extension methods are declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# can statically use classes to permit access to statically defined methods; extension methods are static.  In the above example, the `.ToDate()` extension method is defined in the `Google.Type.DateExtensions` class (in the `Google.Type` namespace), so it's possible to statically use *that class only* to get access to its extension methods, rather than importing the entire `Google.Type` namespace.

This code works:

```cs
using System;
using static Google.Type.DateExtensions;

namespace Example
{
    public class ExampleClass
    {
        public Google.Type.Date TomorrowDate(DateTime date) => date.AddDays(1).ToDate();
    }
}
```

Original answer: https://github.com/googleapis/gax-dotnet/issues/418